# TypeError: _this2.function is not a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class, es6-modules

I have a small library with few classes. In one of the class, i am using method from other classes, thus I instantiate them, and use it in the code.

Some of the classes I use reference method with the `this` keyword.

example:

```
// index.js
import Class1 from './class1'
import Class2 from './class2'
import Class3 from './class3'

export {
   Class1,
   Class2,
   Class3
}

// class1.js
export default Class1 {
   func1() {
      return 'something';
   }

  func2() {
      return this.func1() + 'else';
  }

}

// class2.js
export default Class2 {
   func1() {
      return 'something';
   }

  func2() {
      return this.func1() + 'else again';
  }

}

// class3.js

import {Class1, Class2} from './index';
const c1 = new Class1();
const c2 = new Class2();

export default Class3 {
   funcNotWorking(){
       return c1.func2() + c2.func3() + 'this does not work'
   }

}
```

I am using this in tests by just importing it:

```
// test.js
const c3 = require('library.js').Class3

// test stuff calling:
c3.funcNotWorking()
```

I am compiling this with webpack and babel loader. This config seems to work as it compiles and everything else works, but this...

I have read that people seem to have trouble with this with React, but this is just Es6. Could someone point me to how to resolve this?

Comment: export default Class2 in class3.js file, are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @ŁukaszKapica you are right. Typo, but this is an example to explain the problem

Comment: Why didn't you create a new instance of a Class3 just like you did with Class1 and Class2?

Comment: @ŁukaszKapica because in my real code, class 3 is a class that composes with methods from the other classes... Some formatting dates, other markdown to html, etc. in some places I need Class 2 and to simplify my life I did Class3 for common workflows. (I am migrating some es5 code.) I corrected another typo

Comment: That's cool but funcNotWorking is an instance method and you are using it like it was a static method

Comment: true, in my real code I did instantiate it:
`const C = require('../../lib/library').Composition;
const cp = new C();`

Comment: @ŁukaszKapica this is my real code https://github.com/EuropeanRespiratorySociety/ers-utils/blob/es6-migration/test/lib/composition.test.js

Comment: You are missing a few things, first '../../lib/library' probably should be '../../src/composition' second you are mixing two styles of importing modules you should rather write import Composition from '../../src/composition';

Comment: @ŁukaszKapica I was intending to migrate my tests as well `/test/lib` for es5 require `test/src` for import statement. Somehow this is losing its way among => functions. I found a way to make it work, but I do not like it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The context is of this is getting lost in my code.

I use recursion, mapping and arrow function in the code that was having problems. The Babel compiled version `_this2` did not follow the context.

I extracted some methods, assigned them in the class constructor and use in the class the extracted method and it compiled correctly.